# How to apply a function only to the first row of a group in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

## Data

I have 3 variables. `Vehicle.ID2` is a unique ID of a vehicle pair, `dV` is the speed difference in lead and following vehicles and `dA` is the acceleration difference which remains constant for some time. So, my grouping variables are `Vehicle.ID2` and `dA`. Following are few rows of original data for only 1 `Vehicle.ID2`:

```
    veh <- structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("907-904", "907-904", "907-904", 
"907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", 
"907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", 
"907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904"
), dA = c(0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 
0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, -0.3162, -0.3162, 
-0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, 
-0.3162), dV = c(-0.0427200000000001, 0.11031, 0.22627, 0.30058, 
0.33838, 0.35264, 0.35803, 0.36481, 0.37677, 0.39292, 0.40961, 
0.42206, 0.42557, 0.416090000000001, 0.39003, 0.34668, 0.296580000000001, 
0.268000000000001, 0.29681, 0.399859999999999, 0.554639999999999
)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", "dA", "dV"
), row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

## Goal

I want to create a new column `OC_DV`. Initially all values of OC_DV are `"no"`. This I can do with:

```
veh$OC_DV <- "no"
```

Now, first I want to split the data by the variables `Vehicle.ID2` and `dA`. Then for every group I want to see if the sign of the first value of `dV` matches with the sign of the last value of `dV`. Based on the conditions of sign match or mismatch, I want to modify only the FIRST value of `OC_DV`. Following is the code:

```
OC_DV[1] <- ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))== sign(tail(dV,1)),  "no",
                     ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==-1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==1, "OPDV",
                            ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==-1,"CLDV","no")))
```

## Problem

I tried using `mutate` and `do` but they produce errors:

```
    veh <- veh %>% 
  group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>%
  mutate(OC_DV[1] = ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))== sign(tail(dV,1)),  "no",
                           ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==-1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==1, "OPDV",
                                  ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==-1,"CLDV","no")))
  )
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>%
  mutate(OC_DV[1] ="



 veh <- veh %>% 
  group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>%
  do(OC_DV[1] = ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))== sign(tail(dV,1)),  "no",
                           ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==-1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==1, "OPDV",
                                  ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==-1,"CLDV","no")))
  )
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>%
  do(OC_DV[1] ="
```

If I drop `[1]` there is no error but then all values in a group are changed:

```
    veh %>% 
  group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>%
  mutate(OC_DV = ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))== sign(tail(dV,1)),  "no",
                                ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==-1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==1, "OPDV",
                                       ifelse(sign(head(dV,1))==1 & sign(tail(dV,1))==-1,"CLDV","no")))
  )
```

What can I do to change only the first value?

## Desired Output:

```
    structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("907-904", "907-904", "907-904", 
"907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", 
"907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", 
"907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904", "907-904"
), dA = c(0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 
0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, 0.43024, -0.3162, -0.3162, 
-0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, -0.3162, 
-0.3162), dV = c(-0.0427200000000001, 0.11031, 0.22627, 0.30058, 
0.33838, 0.35264, 0.35803, 0.36481, 0.37677, 0.39292, 0.40961, 
0.42206, 0.42557, 0.416090000000001, 0.39003, 0.34668, 0.296580000000001, 
0.268000000000001, 0.29681, 0.399859999999999, 0.554639999999999
), OC_DV = c("OPDV", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", 
"dA", "dV", "OC_DV"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: Your `dput` throw errors...

Comment: Also please remove `>` and `+` line starters. We can't copy and paste code that way.

Comment: @Sotos and @Axeman, I've fixed the `dput` and removed `>` & `+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

A slightly more clear condition function:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  switch(
    paste(sign(head(x,1)), sign(tail(x,1))),
    '-1 1' = 'OPDV',
    '1 -1' = 'CLDV',
    'no'
   )
}
```

And then we apply the function to only the rows that are first in the group.

```
veh %>% 
  group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>% 
  mutate(OC_DV = if_else(row_number() == 1, fun(dV), 'no'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another idea with a lot of `mutate`,

```
library(dplyr) 
veh %>% 
   group_by(Vehicle.ID2, dA) %>% 
   mutate(id = seq(dV)) %>% 
   mutate(OC_DV = fun1(dV)) %>% 
   mutate(OC_DV = ifelse(id == 1, OC_DV, 'no'))
```

where,

```
fun1 <- function(x){ifelse(sign(head(x,1))== sign(tail(x,1)),  "no",
                           ifelse(sign(head(x,1))==-1 & sign(tail(x,1))==1, "OPDV",
                                  ifelse(sign(head(x,1))==1 & sign(tail(x,1))==-1,"CLDV","no")))}
```

Comment: All those mutates can be combined into one, you can refer to variables in earlier lines.